# Mirror maker thread failure

Tags: apache-kafka

I have swarm network configured when try run Kafka MirrorMake from service inside a docker stack, I get an error from service logs:

```
mirroring_mirror_maker | [2019-01-10 12:08:49,322] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-1] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
mirroring_mirror_maker | java.lang.IllegalStateException: No entry found for connection 2147482646
```

My `consumer.properties` code:

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka:9094
group.id=mm-consumer-group
partition.assignment.strategy=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor
```

Take a look in the code of `producer.properties` bellow:

```
bootstrap.servers=10.1.1.10:9094
compression.type=none
```

Running command from docker stack:

```
kafka-mirror-maker.sh --consumer.config /opt/kafka/config/consumer.properties --num.streams 2 --producer.config /opt/kafka/config/producer.properties --whitelist=".*"
```

If I run the same command from my host machine, it works.

---

More logging output:

```
[2019-01-10 16:14:33,470] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No entry found for connection 2147482646
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.nodeState(ClusterConnectionStates.java:330)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClusterConnectionStates.disconnected(ClusterConnectionStates.java:134)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.initiateConnect(NetworkClient.java:885)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.ready(NetworkClient.java:276)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.tryConnect(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:548)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$FindCoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:655)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$FindCoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:635)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:575)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:389)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:215)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1214)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1179)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1164)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$ConsumerWrapper.receive(MirrorMaker.scala:481)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread.run(MirrorMaker.scala:370)
[2019-01-10 16:14:33,487] ERROR [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, the solution are quick simple, I had to add a host mapping with `extra_hosts` in my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3.6'

x-proxy: &proxy
  http_proxy: ${http_proxy}
  https_proxy: ${https_proxy}
  no_proxy: ${no_proxy}

services:
  mirror_maker:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.1.0
    configs:
      - source: mm-consumer-config
        target: /opt/kafka/config/consumer.properties
      - source: mm-producer-config
        target: /opt/kafka/config/producer.properties
    environment:
      <<: *proxy
    command: kafka-mirror-maker.sh --consumer.config /opt/kafka/config/consumer.properties --num.streams 2 --producer.config /opt/kafka/config/producer.properties --whitelist=.*
    networks:
      - workshop
    extra_hosts:
      - outside:10.1.1.10
      - manager:10.1.1.11
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    deploy:
      # replicas: 2
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

configs:
  mm-consumer-config:
    file: ./services/mirror_maker/config/consumer.properties
  mm-producer-config:
    file: ./services/mirror_maker/config/producer.properties

networks:
  workshop:
    name: workshop
    external: true
```